# How to pull/override local branch from updates from a different local branch?

Tags: git

So we have master that I do not touch and I'm currently working on feature/project.

I've been doing tons of work on feature/project and then had someone else do a couple things while I was out of office.

His code is the most up to date and it's up on BitBucket.

How do I pull his code and replace my local branch?

EDIT:
I did try doing:

1. git reset --hard feature/project to no avail
2. git fetch, git reset --hard origin/feature/project to no avail
3. git fetch origin, git reset --hard origin/feature/project, git clean -f -d to no avail

Comment: isn't it just ```git pull origin feature/project```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
git checkout master
git fetch <url> <his-branch>
git reset FETCH_HEAD --hard
```

`url` is the link to the BitBucket repository. `his-branch` is the branch where his code is. The commands make your local `master` point to his latest commit. If you'd like to update the `master` of your own remote repository, you need `git push origin -f master`. But doing so, some commits of your local `master` would get lost. If you'd like to keep them, run `git merge FETCH_HEAD` instead of `git reset FETCH_HEAD --hard`.